# Showing a label1.text to another form by click a button on another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I guys I would like to ask for your help because I am writing a program in vb.net using visual studio 2010 and what I want to do is to show a text to label1 on form 2 by click a button on form1...thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 Dim xFrm As New SecondForm
 xFrm.Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text
 xFrm.Show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fm As New Form2
        Label1.Text = fm.Label1.Text
End Sub
```